# How to make EF efficiently call an aggregate function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to write a LINQ-to-entities query that will take an `ICollection` navigation property of my main object and attach some metadata to each of them which is determined through joining each of them to another DB table and using an aggregate function.  So the main object is like this:

```
public class Plan
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

And my query is this:

```
var roomData = (
    from rm in plan.Rooms
    join conf in context.Conferences on rm.Id equals conf.RoomId into cjConf
    select new {
        RoomId = rm.Id,
        LastUsedDate = cjConf.Count() == 0 ? (DateTime?)null : cjConf.Max(conf => conf.EndTime)
    }
).ToList();
```

What I want is for it to generate some efficient SQL that uses the aggregate function `MAX` to calculate the `LastUsedDate`, like this:

```
SELECT
    rm.Id, MAX(conf.EndTime) AS LastUsedDate
FROM
    Room rm
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Conference conf ON rm.Id = conf.RoomId
WHERE
    rm.Id IN ('a967c9ce-5608-40d0-a586-e3297135d847', '2dd6a82d-3e76-4441-9a40-133663343d2b', 'bb302bdb-6db6-4470-a24c-f1546d3e6191')
GROUP BY
    rm.id
```

But when I profile SQL Server it shows this query from EF:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[RoomId] AS [RoomId], 
    [Extent1].[ProviderId] AS [ProviderId], 
    [Extent1].[StartTime] AS [StartTime], 
    [Extent1].[EndTime] AS [EndTime], 
    [Extent1].[Duration] AS [Duration], 
    [Extent1].[ParticipantCount] AS [ParticipantCount], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[ServiceType] AS [ServiceType], 
    [Extent1].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
    [Extent1].[InstantMessageCount] AS [InstantMessageCount]
    FROM [dbo].[Conference] AS [Extent1]
```

So it is selecting *everything* from `Conference` and doing the `Max()` calculation in memory, which is very inefficient.  How can I get EF to generate the proper SQL query with the aggregate function in?

Comment: Your query originates from materialized object (`plan`), hence the whole query will execute in LINQ to Objects context. Which means `context.Conferences` is treated as `IEnumerable`, thus loading the whole table in memory. Change the query root to `context.Rooms` for instance.

Comment: @mjwills EF 6.2.0.

Comment: @IvanStoev But if I use `context.Rooms` how do I filter down to just the rooms associated with `Plan`?

Comment: You can start from `context.Plans` if you wish, or start with `context.Rooms` and use something like `.Where(room => room.PlanId == plan.Id)`. The point is to start with EF `IQueryable`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I need to filter down `Rooms` to a list of plan IDs with an `IN` clause, using something like `where plan.Rooms.Any(plRm => plRm.Id == rm.Id)` but that gives an exception about needing a primitive type.

Comment: Nope. You would use something like `context.Rooms.Where(room => planIds.Contains(room.PlanId))`.

Comment: @IvanStoev So you have to use the method syntax for that `Where`?  Is there no equivalent way to do that with query syntax?

Comment: There is nothing special, hence standard `from rm in context.Rooms where planIds.Contains(rm.Id)` should do.

Comment: OK, but I don't have `planIds`.  Is there no way I can use the existing `plan.Rooms.Id` to filter down the room IDs?  I already have all the room IDs that I need for the plan in memory.

Comment: Why don't you use `where rm.PlanId == plan.Id` as filter then? Are `plan.Rooms` additionally filtered? But you can always do `var roomIds = plan.Rooms.Select(rm => rn.Id); var query = from rm in context.Rooms where roomsIds.Contains(rm.Id) …`

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah I can do that actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent LINQ to Entities query which closely translates to the SQL query you are after is like this:

```
var roomIds = plan.Rooms.Select(rm => rm.Id);

var query =
    from rm in context.Rooms
    join conf in context.Conferences on rm.Id equals conf.RoomId
    into rmConf from rm in rmConf.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
    where roomIds.Contains(rm.Id)
    group conf by rm.Id into g
    select new
    {
        RoomId = g.Key,
        LastUsedDate = g.Max(conf => (DateTime?)conf.EndTime)
    };
```

The trick is to start the query from EF `IQueryable`, thus allowing it to be fully translated to SQL, rather than from `plan.Rooms` as in the query in question which is `IEnumerable` and makes the whole query execute in memory (`context.Conferences` is treated as `IEnumerable` and causes loading the whole table in memory).

The SQL `IN` clause is achieved by in memory `IEnumerable<Guid>` and `Contains` method.

Finally, there is no need to check the count. SQL naturally handles `null`s, all you need is to make sure to call the nullable `Max` overload, which is achieved with the `(DateTime?)conf.EndTime` cast. There is no need to check `conf` for `null` as in LINQ to Objects because LINQ to Entities/SQL handles that naturally as well (as soon the receiver variable is nullable).

Comment: There's no need to query `context.Rooms` is there? I think `context.Conferences` contains everything that's needed unless OP wants to see more `Room` data. BTW `Contains(room.Id)` should be `Contains(rm.Id)`.

Comment: @Gert I guess you are right (as usual :) for the concrete scenario (hence the UV). I'm just trying to show how to "port" the desired SQL query. And btw, thanks for pointing out the typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `plan.Rooms` isn't `IQueryable` with a query provider attached, the join statement is compiled as `Enumarable.Join`. This means that `context.Conferences` is implicitly cast to `IEumerable` and its content is pulled into memory before other operators are applied to it.

You can fix this by not using `join`:

```
var roomIds = plan.Rooms.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();
var maxPerRoom = context.Conferences
    .Where(conf => roomIds.Contains(conf.RoomId))
    .GroupBy(conf => conf.RoomId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        RoomId = g.Key,
        LastUsedDate = g.Select(conf => conf.EndTime)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Max()
    }
).ToList();

var roomData = (
    from rm in plan.Rooms
    join mx in maxPerRoom on rm.Id equals mx.RoomId
    select new 
    {
        RoomId = rm.Id,
        LastUsedDate = mx.LastUsedDate
    }
).ToList();
```

This first step collects the `LastUsedDate` data from the context and then joins with the `plan.Rooms` collection in memory. This last step isn't even necessary if you're not interested in returning/displaying anything else than the room's Id, but that's up to you.

Comment: That's no good - it still has to go off to the DB once per room.  That might result in 1000 queries!

Comment: Query rewritten.